# Accessing SharePoint from another domain

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have following scenario:

SharePoint 2013 standalone installation, server is in xyz.local domain so users can simply access SharePoint Sites if they are in the domain. No host names were configured.

Now I need to add users from other office to SharePoint, but the other office is in different domain. How can I provide the users from other office access to SharePoint and what authentication method I shall use?

Comment: You say "a different domain" ... are there firewalls incorporated there which may interfere? If so, there are things which will have to happen before you can have them access it through SP means.

Answer (score 1):

Using Forms Authentication which uses the "other domain" will be an option to consider.

However you will need

1. port 389 (LDAP) or 636 (LDAPS) to be opened on any of the DCs in the "other domain"
2. service account on "other domain" whose password does not expire

Then follow the guide at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34684

One additional step to the above guide is to include connectionUsername and connectionPassword in all the web.config section identified in the link above (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ronalg/archive/2014/04/14/sharepoint-2013-and-forms-based-authentication-configuration-for-open-ldap.aspx for example of these two key value pairs).

Answer (score 1):

The domains need to have trust relationships. If they do, then you can just configure the people picker in SharePoint 2010 to query from the additional domains so you can add user access:

Here are steps to configure SharePoint to authenticate cross domain users.

- Open Internal Firewall.
- configure a One way trust. SharePoint Domain trust the other domain.
- Run People picker command switch.
- Configure your Browser for authentication.

http://www.quantumofgeek.com/2010/09/configure-sharepoint-to-authenticate-cross-forest-ad-users/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602068.aspx#forests